# How to use alertcondition with an if statement inside a for loop

Tags: pine-script

I Wanted to execute an alert function inside a for loop in my pinescript indicator

Here Is an Example

```
for x
    triggerShort = if y
        true
    else
        false

alertcondition(condition=triggerShort,title='test', message='test2')
```

Thanks For Your Help In Advance

Comment: Can you tell us why do you want to trigger alerts within a loop?

Comment: Because in order to trigger my if condition i need to loop over some data that i aquire by looping over something ( the code is just a oversimplified verision )

Comment: But why don’t you set a variable inside the loop and use it as a condition to the `alertcondition` outside the loop as you did in the example?

Comment: Can you maybe simplify your code and share it?

Comment: i ve tried that but when i try to compile the script it says that i have not defined or declared the variable  . its strage for me that pinescript cannot detect a variable defined inside a for loop and use it outside

Comment: That is because it will lose its scope outside of the for block. Try giving it a global scope by declaring it on top level (outside of any function, if/for blocks etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If there is necessity to generate several amount of alerts inside loops you need to use `alert()` function instead.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")


var allowTrigger = false
var triggerShort = false
for x = 1 to 10
    if close > open and allowTrigger   // "some calculations resulting in true or false" 
        alert('test2')
        allowTrigger := true

// some additional event    
allowTrigger  : = false
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer I tried it but I discovered a new problem my script triggers long and short signals all through the chart in a range of 300bars and I cannot lower the range because the data may be unreliable with lower scopes. however, with the solution above the problem is that my alert gets triggered every time my if condition triggers in the chart. but I only want it to be triggered upon an event and a new point of signal ( for example i get 4 long signals starting from 1 day ago but i only want an alert upon the generation of the fifth one)

Comment: You can add any `var` variable and control when you want to trigger alert. Updated example.